# Taquito: error when using "parameter" in withTransfer with Batch API

Tags: smart-contracts, taquito, transfer

I am trying to transfer an amount to a contract while calling a contract endpoint using the Batch API provided by Taquito. I've tried passing a parameter object as shown in the Taquito documentation, this returns an error.

[image: Taquito wesbite]

Here is my code:

[image: My code]

And here is the result:

[image: Result]

As you can see, the returned error is not entirely clear. The closest I can get to solving this is that the "value" property of the parameter object only accepts a MichelsonV1Expression.

Does anyone have a better idea? Is there is a better way to do this, perhaps chaining `withContractCall(contract.methods.mint(1))` after each withTransfer method?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the value property of the parameter object did the trick. It's basically just a json object { int: '1' } but with integers represented as a string.